# How to create a method rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, and am struggling to understand the structure and where and how a method should be instanced.  I have now pretty much confused myself.

This works perfectly in a view the problem is, this is not obeying the MCV rules.

```
      <%  @showblog.showruns.group(:spec_vote).count.each do |spec,count| %>
      Spec: <%=" #{spec}"%>  Votes:  <%=" #{count}" %> <br/> 
      <% end %>
```

My view should be
          <%= @voted.inspect %>  or similar.

with all the other stuff somewhere else. 
In some scenario, all that appears on the view is `{}` which is a nil or nil itself.

My latest try:

```
    class Voted < ActiveRecord::Base
    def voted(spec,count)
    @showblog = Showblog.find(params[:showblog_id])
    @voted =  @showblog.showruns.group(:spec_vote).count.each do |spec,count|
     " Spec:#{spec} Votes: #{count}"
     end end end
```

This has a nil.

I have added this in various place to try see what is going wrong but even with a "no method error" I still don't know where I should see it.
logger.error "--------(some word so I know the file name)-------#{@showblog.inspect}"
My app is on heroku.com

```
class Showblog < ActiveRecord::Base (parent) has_many :showruns, dependent: :destroy end
class Showrun < ActiveRecord::Base (child) belongs_to :showblog end
```

Both controllers contain the normal CRUD and work fine.

Comment: It's not really clear what your question is. Many times asking the question in a way that others can understand it can actually help you better understand the problem yourself.

Comment: See if this makes any sense.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165948/using-a-method-within-model-calling-it-from-view/18166048#18166048

Comment: For better understanding about methods check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225543/how-can-i-call-methods-within-controller-ror

Comment: My question is where, that code that is currently working in the view supposed to be.  If I am to understand the MCV structure the view's only job is to interact with a browser.  Somehow a model should be looking the the database, doing the sort and giving it back to the browser. All the tutorials I have read say not to have business logic in the view and to keep the controller clean and tidy. Right now, I am asking the view to go have a look in the database, sort and then present to the browser. Surely the view should just blindly show whatever a model or controller gives it to display.

Answer (score 0):

In models and controllers, you would better not add the logic of view in them. The best method is using helpers in views.

in your app/helpers/application_helper.rb or the other helper files, add this

```
def vote_spec(blog)
  result = ''
  blog.showruns.group(:spec_vote).count.each do |spec,count|
    result << "Spec: #{spec}  Votes: #{count} <br/>"
    # or the other logic you want to add such as using a table or div
  end
  result.html_safe
end
```

in your view:

```
<%= vote_spec(@showblog) %>
```

Comment: exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks.